# Java program grading

Tags: java

I've been working on this program for hours and I can't figure out how to get the program to actually print the grades from the scores Text file

```
public class Assign7{
  private double finalScore;
  private double private_quiz1;
  private double private_quiz2;
  private double private_midTerm;
  private double private_final;
  private final char grade;

  public Assign7(double finalScore){
    private_quiz1 = 1.25;
    private_quiz2 = 1.25;
    private_midTerm = 0.25;
    private_final = 0.50;

       if (finalScore >= 90) {
           grade = 'A';
       } else if (finalScore >= 80) {
           grade = 'B';
       } else if (finalScore >= 70) {
           grade = 'C';
       } else if (finalScore>= 60) {
           grade = 'D';
       } else {
           grade = 'F';
       }
}


  public String toString(){
    return finalScore+":"+private_quiz1+":"+private_quiz2+":"+private_midTerm+":"+private_final;

  }
}
```

this code compiles as well as this one

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Assign7Test{
  public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception{

  int q1,q2;
  int m = 0;
  int f = 0;
  int Record ; 
  String name;

    Scanner myIn = new Scanner( new File("scores.txt") );

    System.out.println( myIn.nextLine() +"  avg  "+"letter");

   while( myIn.hasNext() ){
      name = myIn.next();
      q1 = myIn.nextInt();
      q2 = myIn.nextInt();
      m = myIn.nextInt();
      f = myIn.nextInt();
       Record myR = new Record( name, q1,q2,m,f);
       System.out.println(myR);

      }
    }

public static class Record {

       public Record() {
       }

       public Record(String name, int q1, int q2, int m, int f)
       { 

       } 
   } 
}
```

once a compile the code i get this which dosent exactly compute the numbers I have in the scores.txt
Name    quiz1     quiz2  midterm   final   avg   letter

Assign7Test$Record@4bcc946b

Assign7Test$Record@642423

```
Exception in thread "main" java.until.InputMismatchException    
    at java.until.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)    
    at java.until.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)    
    at java.until.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)        
    at java.until.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)    
    at Assign7Test.main(Assign7Test.java:25)
```

Comment: Can you post your `scores.txt`?

Comment: What do the lines in the file look like? I don't think java is smart enough to dissect the file for you simply by calling nextInt over and over.

Answer (score 4):

Exception aside, you actually *are* printing objects of type `Record`.  What you would need to do is override `toString()` to provide a decent representation of your object.

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Something meaningful about your Record object.";
}
```

I also note that you're advancing the Scanner by use of `nextLine()` in `System.out.println('...')`.  You may want to comment that part out of your code.

Comment: @pasito: It would be hard to know how to reply to "I am confused". Consider telling us *what* confuses you.

Comment: isn't that what this line is for ?                               public String toString(){
return finalScore+":"+private_quiz1+":"+private_quiz2+":"+private_midT

Comment: @pasito: that's a toString() method. When you call System.out.println(...) the parameters `toString()` method gets called. You're seeing the default `toString()` method that all objects inherit from Object. To have your println's make sense, you need to create your own `toString()` method that returns information that describes the state of your object.

Comment: @pasito: yes, but you don't have a `toString()` method in the ***Score*** class, and that's where it's needed since you're printing out Score objects.

Comment: I added the toString() method to the score class but i still get the same message except for the adrees

Comment: @pasito: please specify *exactly* what the new toString method looks like and *exactly* what you're now seeing printed out.

Comment: this is what i change                                                   public static class Record {

            public Record() {
            }

            public Record(String name, int q1, int q2, int m, int f)
            { 

           } 
           public String toString(){
             return "q1+q2+m+f";

Comment: the output was the same as before

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I posted what i changed avobe

Comment: @pasito15:  First, nothing's being stored in that object, so I would imagine that `null` would be printed a fair bit from `toString` - if the variables weren't in quotes.  Second, be sure to close off that method block and class.  Third, did you fix the issue with Scanner advancing one space before you actually read anything in?

Comment: I just don't know what to write after return

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting this error is because of the fact that you are expecting an integer, but the next thing your scanner reads is not a number.

Also, put this in your toString of your record to stop printing out addresses.

i.e.

```
public static class Record {

   public Record() {
   }

   public Record(String name, int q1, int q2, int m, int f)
   { 

   }
    public String toString(){}//print out stuff here.
```

}

Comment: public String toString(){
    return q1+":"q2+":"m":"f";

Comment: is that what i am suppose to add

Answer (score 0):

change your Record to something like this

```
public static class Record {  
    String name;
    int q1;
    int q2;
    int m;
    int f;

    public Record() {}         
    public Record(String name, int q1, int q2, int m, int f) {
        // here you save the given arguments localy in the Record.
        this.name = name;
        this.q1 = q1;
        this.q2 = q2;
        this.m = m;
        this.f = f;
    }
@Override
public String toString(){
   //here you write out the localy saves variables.
   //this function is called when you write System.out.println(myRecordInstance);
   System.out.println(name + ":" + q1 + ":" + q2 + ":" + m + ":" + f);
}
```

}

What it does: you have to save the argments by creating the Record.
Additional you have to override the toString method if you want to use System.out.println(myRecordInstance); instead you could write an other function returning a String in your Record and print out the return values of this function like `System.out.println(myRecordInstace.writeMe());` Then you ne to add the function to the record.

```
public String writeMe(){
System.out.println(name + ":" + q1 + ":" + q2 + ":" + m + ":" + f);
}
```